# Double summation help

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am trying to reduce the double summation to one summation.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \binom{n+i-1}{i} n^{i+j} .$$

Any suggestions on how to reduce it?

Answer (score 2):

For $|n|<1$, we have
$$
\lvert \binom{n+i-1}{i}n^i\rvert\leq\frac{|n|(|n|+1)\cdots(|n|+i-1)}{i!}|n|^i\leq \frac{i!}{i!}|n|^i=|n|^i
$$
so the series $\sum_{i\geq 0}\binom{n+i-1}{i}n^i$ converges absolutely.

Also, for $|n|<1$, $\sum_{j\geq 0}n^j$ converges absolutely to $1/(1-n)$

So for $|n|<1$, your double series converges absolutely and the following transformation is justified by Fubini, observing that $n^{i+j}=n^in^j$:

$$\sum_{i\geq 0}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{n+i-1}{i}n^{i+j} =\left(\sum_{i\geq 0}\binom{n+i-1}{i}n^i\right) \left(\sum_{j\geq 0}n^j\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-n}\sum_{i\geq 0}\binom{n+i-1}{i}n^i.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \binom{n+i-1}{i} n^{i+j}= 
\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \binom{n+i-1}{n-1}n^i \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} n^{j}
$$

Unfortunately, this series diverges. :-(

Comment: For $|n|<1$, it converges.

Comment: To  julien: Yes, but $n+i-1\le i$ !

Comment: ? $n$ can be any complex number in the formula $\binom{n+i-1}{i}=\frac{(n+i-1)(n+i-1)\cdots n}{i!}$. I don't see the problem. Indeed, for $n\leq 1$, you have $n+i-1\leq i$... And? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @  julien: I supposed that the author deals with integers. If no, then you are right.